# Org links to regex under portable subtree

Tags: org-mode, org-link

Is it possible to have links like this?

```
[[id:a5e9935a-9b82-480d-9c27-74a71bfac27a::/regex/]]
```

That is, links to a match under a portable subtree?
This, at least, did not work.

(By portable subtree, I just mean a subtree that has a randomly
generated ID, so that links to it still work after it has been refiled.)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do. What is a portable subtree?

Comment: You can make your own link type for that.